# What is the correct function block?

Tags: c++, function, integer, display, getcolor

***the following code is for a rectangle assignment. however not certain if my get color was entered correctly. looking to see if someone can help me with this matter.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
double getLength();
double getWidth();
int getColor();
double getArea(double, double);
void displayData(double, double, double, string);

int main()
{
    double length;    // The rectangle's length
    double width;     // The rectangle's width
    double area;      // The rectangle's area

    string color;        // The rectangle's color

   
    // Get the rectangle's length.
    length = getLength();

    // Get the rectangle's width.
    width = getWidth();

    // Get the rectangle's color   
    color = getColor();

    // Get the rectangle's area.
    area = getArea(length, width);

    // Display the rectangle's data.
    displayData(length, width, area, color);
    
    return 0;
}

//***************************************
// getLength                            *
//***************************************

double getLength()
{
    double length; // rectangle's length and return value as a double.

    // Get the length
    cout << "Enter the length: ";
    cin >> length;

    return length;
}
   
//***************************************
// getWidth                             *
//***************************************

double getWidth()
{
    double width; // rectangle's width and return valus as a double.

    // Get the width
    cout << "Enter the width: ";
    cin >> width;

    return width;
}

//***************************************
// getColor                             *
//***************************************

int getColor()
{
    int color; // rectangle's color.

    // Get the color
    cout << "Choose your color by typing the number next to your color \n 1 Blue \n 2 Red \n 3 Green \n 4 Yellow \n 5 Pink \n 6 Orange ";

    string blue = "Blue";
    string red = "Red";
    string green = "Green";
    string yellow = "Yellow";
    string pink = "Pink";
    string orange = "Orange";
    cin >> color;
    if (color == 1)
    {
        cout << blue;
        color = 1;
    };
    if (color == 2)
    {
        cout << red;
        color = 2;
    };
    if (color == 3)
    {
        cout << green;
        color = 3;
    };
    if (color == 4)
    {
        cout << yellow;
        color = 4;
    };
    if (color == 5)
    {
        cout << pink;
        color = 5;
    };
    if (color == 6)
    {
        cout << orange;
        color = 6;
    };

    return color;
}

//***************************************
// getArea                              *
//***************************************

double getArea(double length, double width)
{
    return length * width;
}

//***************************************
//displayData                           *
//***************************************

void displayData(double length, double width, double area, string color)
{

    cout << "\n Rectangle Data \n"
        << "------------- \n"
        << "Length: " << length << endl
        << "Width: " << width << endl
        << "Color: "<< color << endl
        << "Area: " << area << endl;
        
}
```

[image]
I have no idea what this squared ? means. did i do something incorrect in my getColor function??

Answer (score 0):

Your `getColor` method returns an `int` and you are assigning it to a `std::string`. You should return the string you are showing the user (so, variables `blue`, `pink`, `red` and so on) which are themselves `std::string` instead of `color`, which is of type `int`.

So, the compiler is taking the `int` that you are returning and using it to initialize the `std::string`. If you debug and take a look at the content, you will see that the content of the string corresponds to the value you enter. For instance, in the case of Blue (1), it is trying to show you the ASCII char 1. If you enter as color choice "65" it will show you color 'A', which corresponds to ASCII 65 (by the way, you should sanitize input so that the user can't enter an invalid value). As to the lack of warnings, I guess it just falls in some of the allowed type conversions for one of the constructors.

As an aside, in `getColor` I would create an array of strings containing the colors instead of N variables.

Comment: But why doesn't the compiler complain about that assignment from `int` to `std::string`? What's actually going on there? Why is there anything in the `string` variable at all? Can you explain that also? Would be great. (Note there's no warning or something like that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0643a874c55fcbd9)

Comment: Why don't you add that explanation to your answer?

Comment: Good idea, just added it to the answer

Comment: getColor – This function should ask the user to enter the rectangle’s color then 
return that value as a string. You will provide the user with a menu of colors to 
select from and return that value as an integer.